# DB2 Date format

Tags: sql, date, db2, date-format

I just want to format current date into `yyyymmdd` in DB2.

I see the date formats available, but how can I use them?

http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z10.doc.intro%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fdb2z_datetimetimestamp.htm

```
SELECT CURDATE() FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1;
```

I dont see any straightforward way to use the above listed formats.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

```
SELECT VARCHAR_FORMAT(CURRENT TIMESTAMP, 'YYYYMMDD')
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Should work on both Mainframe and Linux/Unix/Windows DB2.  [Info Center entry for `VARCHAR_FORMAT()`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_11.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0007110.html).

Comment: that works . thanks .. can you also tell how can i substarct days from the above date ........................................................ like                                            CURDATE() - ( 3 day )

Comment: It looks like you already have it.  :)  `CURRENT TIMESTAMP - 3 DAY`

Comment: Keep in mind once converted the result may include blanks to the right of values, depending on the db2 version. The column result will be 255 long.

Answer (score 4):

One more solution 
REPLACE (CHAR(current date, ISO),'-','')

Answer (score 4):

```
select to_char(current date, 'yyyymmdd') from sysibm.sysdummy1
```

result: 20160510

Comment: The query not working. It return :

SQL0440N  No authorized routine named "TO_CHAR" of type "FUNCTION" having
compatible arguments was found.  SQLSTATE=42884

Comment: Works here - shortest and best solution for me. Cited from DB2 docs: _The TO_CHAR scalar function is a synonym for the VARCHAR_FORMAT scalar function._

Answer (score 1):

This isn't straightforward, but

```
SELECT CHAR(CURRENT DATE, ISO) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

returns the current date in yyyy-mm-dd format.  You would have to substring and concatenate the result to get yyyymmdd.

```
SELECT SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE, ISO), 1, 4) ||
    SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE, ISO), 6, 2) ||
    SUBSTR(CHAR(CURRENT DATE, ISO), 9, 2)
FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Comment: thanks .. but is this the only way to do it? then what is the use of formats ....   DATE_K YYYYMMDD   ??

Comment: I couldn't get the ALTDATE function to work on my DB2.  What I posted in my answer works.

Answer (score 1):

Current date is in `yyyy-mm-dd` format. You can convert it into `yyyymmdd` format using `substring` function:

```
select substr(current date,1,4)||substr(current date,6,2)||substr(currentdate,9,2)
```